# Finding c knowing $c = 3k + 2$, $c = 4l + 3$ and $100 \leq c \leq 110$

Tags: diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I need to model and solve the problem with a **diophantine equation**. As title says, the things I know are:
\begin{align*}
c &= 3k + 2 \\
c &= 4l + 3 & \text{and } 100 \leq c \leq 110 \\
\end{align*}

**Edit:** I've found that the result is 107, because:

$$26\cdot 4 + 3 = 107$$
and
$$35\cdot 3+2=107$$

but I'm still not able to recognize how to model it with a diophantine equation.

Comment: what are the meaning of $$q_1,q_2$$?

Comment: $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ are integers. what I've wanted to point out was that the remaining of the division of c by 3 is 2 and by 4 is 3. I will replace $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ by $k$ and $l$ resp. to make things more clear. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solving your Diophanine equation
$$3k-4l=1$$ we get $$k=3+4m,l=2+3m$$ where $m$ is an arbitrary integer number.
Can you finish now?

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand the reasoning. you made $c = 3k+2=4l+3 = c$ ending in the diphantine equation that you solved. so now with the general solution to that particular equation, how its posible to find out $c$?

Comment: we get $$c=11+12m$$ band you have to solve $$100\le 11+12m\le 110$$

Comment: Oh. I was failing to see what you were doing there. When you found that $k = 3 + 4m$ you went back to $c = 3k+2$ and by substituting you get $c = 11 + 12m$. With $l$ you end up with the same result. Then it's easy to see that:
\begin{align*}
\text{If m = 7 then } 11 + 12m=95 \\
\text{If m = 8 then } 11+12m=107\\
\text{If m = 9 then } 11+12m=119\\
\end{align*}
So the answer is 107.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: indeed a nice problem

Comment: Just as a curiosity the original problem statement is something like this: A woman has a basket and an amount of apples. She tries to fit the apples in the basket in groups so she doesn't have to leave any behind. If she makes groups of 3 she has to leave 2 apples. If she makes groups of 4 apples, she has to leave 3. How many apples does she have?